# How to make a sql command with a php while loop in it

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to make a sql while loop.
The idea:

```
$command = SELECT fr_id from fr WHERE GB_ID = $ID;
$row = MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY($command);
```

With that info i want to make an while loop

```
$command2 = SELECT * FROM br WHERE GB_ID = while (results are comming) { $ row[FR_ID];
}
```

Some of you know this wont work like this. I am trying to make this work but anyone any idea how to do this ?!

Comment: This makes no sense at all. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to make a while loop that adds up id to the where id is so you get something like WHERE GB_ID = 1, 7 , 8

Comment: Have a look at IN clause of SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want is

```
SELECT * FROM br WHERE GB_ID IN (SELECT fr_id from fr WHERE GB_ID = $ID);
```

Here the `IN` keyword means that GB_ID will be matched to be equal to any number of a set. the set used is another Select query in this case.